# Conditionally rename the value depending on the previous row

Tags: r, conditional-statements, rename

I have a data frame **df**:

```
Event       Code
Picture     no$
Picture     value
Picture     $
Picture     value
Picture     no$
Picture     value
Picture     no$
Picture     value
Picture     $
Picture     value
```

I want to rename *value* to *reward* or *no_reward* depending on the previous row. If it's *$* then *reward*, if it's *no$* then *no_reward*

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another idea,

```
df1$Code[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- ifelse(df1$Code[c(TRUE, FALSE)] == 'no$', 'no_reward', 'reward')
df1
#     Event      Code
#1  Picture       no$
#2  Picture no_reward
#3  Picture         $
#4  Picture    reward
#5  Picture       no$
#6  Picture no_reward
#7  Picture       no$
#8  Picture no_reward
#9  Picture         $
#10 Picture    reward
```

**Note**: This assumes that for every `$` or `no$`, a `value` follows

Comment: it creates NAs instead. what are the F and T? false and true?

Comment: Well yes...if you have it saved as df. I named it df1 in my env.

Comment: ok, thanks. I am trying to run it again and it shows me this error 

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, c(F, T), value = c(31L, NA, 25L, NA, 22L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: maybe it's because I have some other variables in my column that I don't need to process...

Comment: Try converting `df$Code` to character first

Comment: it worked. aonly I had to change the code:
    df$Code[c(T, F)] <- ifelse(df$Code[c(F, T)] == 'no$', 'no_reward', 'reward')

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method with `ifelse`, subsetting, and `which`:

```
df$Code[which(df$Code=="value")] <- 
       ifelse(df$Code[which(df$Code=="value") - 1] == "$", "reward", "no_reward")
```

Or a probably faster method that doesn't use `ifelse`:

```
df$Code[which(df$Code=="value")] <-
      c("reward", "no_reward")[(df$Code[which(df$Code=="value") - 1] == "$") + 1]
```

Both return

```
df
     Event      Code
1  Picture       no$
2  Picture no_reward
3  Picture         $
4  Picture    reward
5  Picture       no$
6  Picture no_reward
7  Picture       no$
8  Picture no_reward
9  Picture         $
10 Picture    reward
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="Event       Code
Picture     no$
Picture     value
Picture     $
Picture     value
Picture     no$
Picture     value
Picture     no$
Picture     value
Picture     $
Picture     value", as.is=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `data.table` and `data.table::shift` for this:

```
require(data.table)

dt = data.table(Event = 'Picture',
                Code = c('no$', 'value', '$', 'value', 'no$', 'value', 'no$', 'value', '$', 'value'))

dt[, Code_l1 := shift(Code)]
dt[Code_l1 == '$', Code := 'reward']
dt[Code_l1 == 'no$', Code := 'no_reward']
dt[, Code_l1 := NULL]
```